# Is it ok to disable docker0 bridge in k8s cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

The default subnet of docker0 is 172.17.x.x/16, it's overlapped with some of the network devices. After doing some search, I found that docker0 can be disabled in /etc/docker/daemon.js, like

> { "bridge": "none"}

None of the containers in my k8s cluster is using docker0 network, I did some test after disabling docker0, everything seems to be working fine, but I wonder if this configuration is normal for a k8s cluster, and if there is any potential risks I overlooked.

Comment: k8s uses custom bridge which is different from docker`s default bridge based on network type to satisfy kubernetes networking model. So this should be fine. In case you want to modify docker bridge CIDR block you can specify this ```--bip=CIDR``` as part of DOCKER_OPTS which is different from cbr0-CIDR.

Comment: It depends on which `kubernetes networking model` you use, but I have never seen `networking model` using docker's bridge. So it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering on behalf of @Barath

> k8s uses custom bridge which is different from docker`s default bridge
>   based on network type to satisfy kubernetes networking model. So this
>   should be fine. In case you want to modify docker bridge CIDR block
>   you can specify this --bip=CIDR as part of DOCKER_OPTS which is
>   different from cbr0-CIDR. – Barath May 22 at 5:06

and @menya

> It depends on which kubernetes networking model you use, but I have
>   never seen networking model using docker's bridge. So it is fine. –
>   menya May 22 at 8:09

Because no further response was given and we should keep answers away from comments section.